# C++/OpenGL - How to get the right variable inherited from class

Tags: c++, opengl, shader

So the problem is that my code is not running the right glUseProgram function.

I've tested what value it should need and it works, but I obviously don't want to hardcode it.

Shader.cpp (I declared the programID in the header file)

```cpp
#include "Shader.h"

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

GLuint vertexShaderID, fragmentShaderID;

Shader::Shader() {

}

Shader::Shader(const GLchar* vertexFile, const GLchar* fragmentFile) {
    GLint success;
    GLchar infoLog[512];

    vertexShaderID = loadShader(vertexFile, GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    fragmentShaderID = loadShader(fragmentFile, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    programID = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(programID, vertexShaderID);
    glAttachShader(programID, fragmentShaderID);
    glLinkProgram(programID);
    //glValidateProgram(programID);

    glGetProgramiv(programID, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(programID, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }

    //bindAttributes();

    std::cout << "SHADER::LOADED\n" << std::endl;

    glDeleteShader(vertexShaderID);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShaderID);
    std::cout << "PROGRAM::" << programID << std::endl;
}

void Shader::Start() const
{
    glUseProgram(programID);
    std::cout << "p:" << programID << std::endl;
}

void Shader::cleanUp() {
    glUseProgram(0);
    glDetachShader(programID, vertexShaderID);
    glDetachShader(programID, fragmentShaderID);
    glDeleteShader(vertexShaderID);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShaderID);
    glDeleteProgram(programID);
}
```

TestShader.cpp

```cpp
#include "TestShader.h"
#include "Shader.h"

const GLchar* VERTEX_FILE = "shaders/shader.vs";
const GLchar* FRAGMENT_FILE = "shaders/shader.frag";

TestShader::TestShader() {
    Shader::Shader(VERTEX_FILE, FRAGMENT_FILE);

}
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>

// GLEW
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>

// GLFW
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

// SOIL
#include <SOIL2/SOIL2.h>

// GLM
#include <GLM/glm.hpp>

// Other includes
#include "TestShader.h"

// GameEngine
#include "Display.h"
#include "Mesh.h"

const GLuint WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 600;

int main()
{
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    Display display(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "GameEngine");

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

    TestShader s;

    Vertex vertices[] = {
        Vertex(glm::vec3(-0.5 , -0.5, 0)),
        Vertex(glm::vec3(0, 0.5, 0)),
        Vertex(glm::vec3(0.5, -0.5, 0))
    };

    Mesh mesh(vertices, sizeof(vertices) / sizeof(vertices[0]));


    while (!display.IsClosed())
    {
        glfwPollEvents();

        display.Clear(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.3f, 0.0f);

        s.Start();

        mesh.Draw();

        s.cleanUp();

        display.Update();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

TestShader.h

```cpp
#ifndef TESTSHADER_H
#define TESTSHADER_H

#include "Shader.h"

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <iostream>

class TestShader : public Shader {
public:
    TestShader();
private:
protected:
    void bindAttributes() override;
};

#endif // TESTSHADER_H
```

Shader.h

```cpp
#ifndef SHADER_H
#define SHADER_H

#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

#include <GL/glew.h>

class Shader
{
private:
    GLuint programID;

protected:
    int getUniformLocation(GLchar * uniformName);

public:
    Shader();
    Shader(const GLchar* vertexFile, const GLchar* fragmentFile);
    ~Shader();

    GLuint loadShader(const GLchar * shaderSourcePath, GLuint type);

    virtual void bindAttributes();
    void bindAttribute(int attribute, GLchar* variableName);
    void Start() const;
    void cleanUp();
};

#endif // !SHADER_H
```

If I cout the programID in the constructor I get the value 3 but if I cout it in the Start function I get a 3435973836 (always.. I think).

There is probably a problem with the inheritance I guess. But why does it work if I hardcode a 3 in the Start function instead of the programID?

The Consoles output (my programID value changes):
[image]

Comment: Please show the definition of the `Shader` class. Why are the vertex and fragment shader ids global variables?

Comment: I think that I only saved them globally to delete them in the cleanUp function. Not sure if that's really needed. But there is ofc a better solution to that.

Comment: That `cleanUp()` call should probably not be in your display loop. But I somewhat doubt that this causes the behavior your seeing.

Comment: @Ahriox Why do you destroy the shader in the display loop? (`s.cleanUp();`)

Comment: For now it's irrelevant, as I said before. My shader works when I put `glUseProgram(3)` in my Start function. My problem here is that why is the programID not 3 anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the constructor of the object `TestShader`:

> ```cpp
> TestShader::TestShader() {
>    Shader::Shader(VERTEX_FILE, FRAGMENT_FILE);
> }
> ```

The statement `Shader::Shader(VERTEX_FILE, FRAGMENT_FILE);` doesn't do what you expect it to do. It doesn't "construct" respectively initialize the base class, it generates a completely new object in scope of the body of the constructor.

You've to specify the constructor of the base class in the initializer-list of the constructor (see [Constructors and member initializer lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)):

```cpp
TestShader::TestShader() 
  : Shader(VERTEX_FILE, FRAGMENT_FILE) {
}
```

Note, in your code actually the attribute `programID` of the object `TestShader s` is never set, because the default constructor is used to construct the base class.
But another object is generated in the body of the constructor of `TestShader`. This object successfully generates the shader program and sets it's own the attribute `programID` (that is what is printed in the first line of the output).
Of course this object is destructed immediately, but that doesn't matter, since the OpenGL shader program object still exists on the GPU.
So the ("hardcoded") call `glUsePrgram(3)` installs the shader program.

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought that my method works as I was expecting it to. Either way, that was kind of confusing at first (coming from mainly c#), but it works now. So again, thx.